# Scrapy Program stops after about 500-600 items

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I hired someone off of freelancer to make this spider for ebay. I am just learning python and needed it quick so that was our solution. I have asked him to figure out what is causing the issue and he has tried but he does not know what this issue is. He says it runs fine on his computer but it crashes on all the ones I try. I have used Ubuntu and Windows. Different computers and at locations with internet.

It was built around python 2.7 and I made sure I have the latest versions of scrapy, selenium, and bs4.

I am running a scrapy spider for ebay. When I run it, it will get through about 500-600 items and then just close the spider.

The program parses the page and extracts the data and saves it to a CSV file without any problem. It goes from one page to the next one just fine too.

Sometimes it will close like this:

```
2017-07-19 15:27:21 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up 
retrying <GET ***link***> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure 
twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost 
in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]

2017-07-19 15:27:21 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET ***link***>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
```

Other times it will just close like this and not give a reason:

```
2017-07-19 13:20:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

The starting link that I give it has 50,000 parts on it, so having it stop around 500 is cutting it a bit short.

Here is the part of the code:

```
import scrapy,time
from urlparse import urljoin
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from ebay.items import EbayItem
url = raw_input("ENTER THE URL TO SCRAPE : ")
co = 1
ch = 1

class EbayspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "ebayspider"
#start_urls = ['http://www.ebay.com/sch/hfinney/m.html?
item=132127244893&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2562']
start_urls = [str(url)]


def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def __del__(self):
    self.driver.quit()


def parse(self, response):
    global ch, co

    try:
        if ch > 5:
            self.driver.quit()
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            ch = 1
            co = 1

        for attr in response.xpath('//*[@id="ListViewInner"]/li'):
            item = EbayItem( )
            linkse = '.vip ::attr(href)'
            link = attr.css('a.vip ::attr(href)').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(urljoin(response.url, link), callback=self.parse_link, meta={'item': item})
        next_page = '.gspr.next ::attr(href)'
        next_page = response.css(next_page).extract_first()
        if next_page:
            ch+=1
            yield scrapy.Request(urljoin(response.url, next_page), callback=self.parse)

    except:

        if ch > 5:
            self.driver.quit()
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            ch = 1
            co = 1


        SET_SELECTOR = '.li.nol'
        for attr in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            item = EbayItem()
            linkse = '.v4lnk ::attr(href)'
            link = attr.css(linkse).extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(urljoin(response.url, link), callback=self.parse_link, meta={'item': item})

        next_page = 'td.next a ::attr(href)'
        next_page = response.css(next_page).extract_first()
        if next_page:
            ch+=1
            yield scrapy.Request(urljoin(response.url, next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

Any Ideas on this issue are welcome, I will try anything.

When the spider closes and is there a way to re-open it from where it left off?

I am not the best with python but I have learned a lot trying to figure this out, I will try just about anything.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I was also experimenting with Selenium and experienced the same problems as you do - sometimes it worked and grabbed all the items, sometimes it stopped in the middle with no error. Didn't find a proper way to solve it, though. I just have a feeling Selenium is a fragile thing to play with... I suspect performance issues, because it worked fine on my PC during development, but failed usually when deployed to Scrapyd instances and run together with other spiders at the same time. I couldn't use Splash back then, because it had old WebKit support. Now with Splash 3.0 I use Splash again, try that

Comment: For clarification you originally your spider was written Python 2.7 but than you moved to 3.0+ later on and that fixed the issue?

Comment: Nope. I'm developing spiders in Python 2.7. I was referring to version of Splash. I used Selenium for one spider only because that page couldn't be rendered with older version of Splash (using old QT/WebKit impementation). It had been working as I wrote - sometime success sometimes not. When Splash docker image was updated, I went back from Selenium to Splash which works great for me.

Comment: What sort of data are you scraping that you need Selenium?

Comment: Part of the program is finding shipping rates. So it pulls the first shipping number and than it has to enter a quantity of 2 and a zip code in texts fields to get the shipping cost if you were to order a quantity of 2. Everything else the I am extracting is text based. Would Splash be able to replace selenium entirely?

Comment: Is Ebay blocking your script?  they probably have code in place to detect robots, and probably don't like robots scraping their site.  That's what their API is for.

Comment: Probably. I am using a fake agent now which helped me get to 2300 items this time but it still stopped. Would a VPN that changes IP addresses be a solution? or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get that information from Ebay Api

Comment: Would a VPN that changes IP addresses be a solution? or something else?

Comment: There is a limit of request on API key so VPN won't help. In that case you need Proxy/VPN + multiple API's

Comment: Okay I will try that